# French Post: What is the difference between "post export" and "lettre prioritaire"

Tags: france, costs, shipping

I am sending small items, less than 50 grams, from France to the US mostly, and normally use "lettre Prioritaire" which takes 1-4 weeks for 1.78 Euro.  I just sent something "post export" for 6.73 Euro because they said 4 days to California. (without tracking)
Has anyone else used "post export"? Are the expected delivery times accurate?  Is this similar to the US Priority mail? Is it worth the extra 5 euro?  Thanks!

Comment: That's interesting, the help center states these are "site worthy" - "Complications in every day life due to living in a foreign country as a non-citizen" The French Post is complicated.  Others may have similar questions, and I found this site was the place to ask this.

Comment: I had a [**related question**](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/1365/133) a few months ago.

Answer (score 2):

After a search on the french *Poste* site, you can see on [this page (in french)](http://www.laposte.fr/particulier/courriers-colis/envoyer-des-lettres-et-colis-vers-le-monde) that *Postexport documents* is an offer for a pre-stamped pack/enveloppe. The price therefore includes this package but the delivery system is described as *Lettre Prioritaire*, so not different from your 1.78 € stamp for a letter under 50g.

On the same page, you can see that there's an offer called *Export Suivi*, that you can add over a letter already stamped as a *Lettre Prioritaire* to benefit tracking of your letter, with no mention of a faster delivery.

So my feeling is that you will not benefit of a faster delivery by using *Postexport*, neither *Export Suivi*.

[This document (in french)](http://www.laposte.fr/particulier/content/download/7839/275968/version/2/file/619105997498e34235562f4f4ed36c21.pdf) mentions a 4 to 11 days for delivery of *Prioritaire* in the USA outside LA and NYC.

Comment: Reviewing these pages, it seems you may be right.  The post export may just be a convenience (costlier) envelope. It will be interesting to see if it arrives sooner than later.